# Accept http, https and www in a OOP filter method

Tags: php, regex, oop, preg-replace-callback

The method below make links clickable. It's a filter. You send the text string and it convert *http* and *https* into clickable links.

```
/**
* Make clickable links from URLs in text.
*
*/
public function make_clickable($text) {

  return preg_replace_callback(
    '#\b(?<![href|src]=[\'"])https?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#',
  create_function(
    '$matches',
    'return "<a href=\'{$matches[0]}\'>{$matches[0]}</a>";'
  ),$text);

}
```

I want to extend this method to accept *www* as well (ex www.google.com), it this possible?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The below string finds *http*, *https* and *www*, but links with type *www* have the wrong *href*. It links to *webroot/www.test.com* for example.

```
'/((http[s]?:|www[.])[^\s]*)/'
```

**SOLUTION**

```
/**
* Make clickable links from URLs in text.
*/
public function make_clickable($text) {

  // Force http to www.
  $text = preg_replace( "(www\.)", "http://www.", $text );

  // Delete duplicates after force.
  $text = preg_replace( "(http://http://www\.)", "http://www.", $text );
  $text = preg_replace( "(https://http://www\.)", "https://www.", $text );

  // The RegEx.
  $regExUrl = "/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

  // Check if there is a URL in the text.
  if(preg_match($regExUrl, $text, $url)) {

    // Make the URLs hyper links.
    $text = preg_replace(
      $regExUrl,
      '<a href="' . $url[0] . '" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">' . $url[0] . '</a>',
      $text
    );

  }    

  return $text;

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean pass in only www.domain.com?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors (didn't escape the `/`). At any rate, if you want to match `www.` just add it into your string directly (remembering to escape the `.`, which is a control character otherwise)

```
preg_replace_callback(
'#\b(?<![href|src]=[\'"])(?:http(?:s|):\/\/|)(?:www\.|)[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|(?:[^[:punct:]\s]|\/))#', ...);
```

Comment: Were you wanting to force `www.`? That's what I wrote it for

Comment: I don't know. I just want it to accept http, https and www in a integral. Right now http and https just works.

Comment: I added something that should better match what you're asking for

Comment: Hmm, the new script made every word in the text a link. The text is a integral, so we need to find http, https or www and just make that part a link.